# Is it possible to cast GenericTypeArray to a Class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm passing a `ByteArray` **type** to a function. In regular JVM/Kotlin environment, the **type** is recognized as a *Class*, `[B`, while in Android environment, somehow the same **type** is recognized as a *GenericArrayType*, `byte[]`.

To reproduce the issue, simply pass the Type `byte[]` into the following function.

```kotlin
fun fromType(type: Type) {
  if (type is Class<*>) {
    // jvm/Kotlin will enter this condition since it's [B
  }

  if (type is GenericArrayType) {
    // android will enter this condition since it's byte[]
  }
}
```

How could it makes the difference with the same input? Is it possible to cast type `byte[]` to `[B`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please do not add code as images. BR

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. It's only for demonstrating the breaking points. I am removing it if it doesn't help. Thanks!